# If $k^n$ no simple $kG$ module, then we can find a basis in a special form.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, linear-groups

I'm reading Lam's book "A first course in noncommutative rings". In the proof of Burnside's First Theorem ((9.4), p151). The statement says:

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p \geq 0$ and let $G$ be a
>   subgroup of $GL_n(k)$. If  $G$ has exponent $N < \infty$ and $p \not|
>  N$, then $|G| \leq N^{(n^3)}$.

In the proof, we can assume that $k$ is algebraically closed.

On a certain moment, the proof makes the following claim:

Assume $k^n$ is a non-simple $kG$-module. Then, after choosing a suitable basis for $k^n$ we may assume that the elements of $G$ have the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}g_1 \ h \\ 0 \ g_2\end{pmatrix}$$
where $g_1, g_2$ are square matrices of fixed size, say $n_1$ and $n_2$. Moreover, $g_i \in GL_{n_i}(k)$ for $i=1,2$.

Why is the above true? How do we choose this basis? Why can we assume our elements change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these matrices are intended to operate on the right of row vectors in $k^n$.

> How do we choose this basis?

If $k^n$ is a nonsimple $kG$ module, it has a proper $kG$ submodule, call it $N$.  After fixing a $k$-basis of $N$, we can go about figuring out just how $G$ acts on $N$, and those will become the matrices that go into the $g_2$ spot.

Now extend the $k$-basis for $N$ to all of $k^n$. Now we can work out representations of elements of $G$ that act on all of $k^n$.  But look: this new matrix has to cause $N$ to be mapped into itself, since $N$ is a $kG$ submodule. Since that happens, it must be that the basis vectors not in $N$ have to be mapped to $0$, and this is what causes the lower left-hand block of zeros.

> Why can we assume our elements change?

The elements don't change... just our representation of them changes. And after all, we are free to represent the vector space with whatever basis we prefer.

> Why is $g_2\in GL_{n_2}(k)$?

Each element of $kG$ is acting as a $k$ linear transformation on the $n_2$ dimensional space $N$, and so it can be represented by a $n_2\times n_2$ matrix, i.e. $g_2$.

$g_1$ is an $n_1\times n_1$ matrix where $n_1=n-n_2$, just by your knowledge of the dimensions of the matrices and the size of that zero block. Using block-matrix arithemtic, you can easily show that the diagonal blocks are invertible, since the matrix is invertible (representing the invertible element $g\in G$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why does have $N$ have a basis?

Comment: @user661541 Because it is a vector subspace of $k^n$. All vector spaces have bases.

Comment: So, you mean a $k$-basis and no $kG$-basis?

Comment: Of course. There is no sense in talking about a basis of a $kG$ module unless you know it is free. And we don't. The $k$-bases are what give us these matrix representations...

Comment: I'll think somewhat about this answer to see if I fully understand it. Thanks again

Comment: @user661541 Good luck! And let me know if I can elaborate somehow, when we meet here again.

Comment: So, I thought a bit about it. I see that we can fix a $k$-basis for $N$: $N= e_1 k \oplus \dots e_{n_1} k$. Then we extend it to a $k$-basis for $k^n$: $k^n = e_1 k \oplus \dots e_{n_1} k \oplus e_{n_1 +1}k \oplus \dots  \oplus e_n k$. Now, I don't see why we can assume that an element of $g$ has this form. The idea is that we can let $k^n$ act on a matrix $g \in G$, but the form in which $g$ should come suggests that one works with something like $N = k^{n_1} \times 0^{n-n_1}$ which isn't the case here. Could you maybe help me further out?

Comment: @user661541 Suppose one of the rows in the bottom half of the matrix $A$ were non zero in the part we think ought to be zeros, say row $j$.  Now, the vectors corresponding to $N$ are those which are zero in the first part. Then the vector with a $1$ in the $j$ position and zeros elsewhere is in $N$, and $NA$  has nonzero entries in the first part (the part outside of $N$.) But that's not possible: $NA\in N$ since $N$ is a $kG$ submodule. See?

Comment: In my comment, the $e_i$ are not necessarily the vectors that are $1$ on one position and $0$ elsewhere. Are you assuming this in your last comment?

Comment: @user661541 The vectors in my comment are not elements of the set $N$, they are the coordinates with respect to the basis you chose. It's an isomorphism of $N$ with $k^n$.Likewise the matrix is the transformation with respect to the basis you chose. If you chose $e_i\in N$ as a basis element, then its corresponding vector is a unit vector.  The matrix equation you are talking about has to be done completely with the coordinate values according to the basis.

Comment: But why do my matrices  'change? In Lam's proposition, $G$ is a linear group of matrices. You say that these matrices change when you choose a basis? Does this mean that you view these matrices as $k$-endomorphisms $k^n \to k^n$?

Comment: @user661541 To represent a transformation $T$ of a vector space $V$ as a matrix, you need to fix a basis first. Different bases yield different matrices.  yes, the whole point of representing a transformation as a matrix is to use matrix multiplication with vectors over the same field.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept! It was really useful!

Comment: @user661541 glad to help

Comment: If you don't mind, I have one follow up question. Why is $g_2 \in GL_{n_2}(k)$? (for $g_1$ I see why this is the case) I can see that the columns of $g$ are independent in $k^n$ and it will probably have something to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But it is still unclear to me why the blocks $g_1, g_2$ are invertible?

Comment: @user661541 It says *the elements of $G$ have the form*, and obviously elements of $G$ are invertible.  So when  $\begin{bmatrix}A&\ast\\0&B\end{bmatrix}$ has block-inverse $\begin{bmatrix}C&\ast\\0&D\end{bmatrix}$, it is trivial to show $A^{-1}=C$ and $B^{-1}=D$.

Comment: Thank you @rschwieb for your help, guidance and patience. Everything is clear now. Have a great day/night!

Comment: @user661541 No problem